# get largest value from NSString is NSArray

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsarray

I have an `NSArray` that for example has the following strings that represent files.

```
"abc1.xml"
"abc2.xml"
"cde1.xml"
"cde2.xml"
"cde3.xml"
"def6.xml"
"def7.xml"
```

Imagine the files are `{prefix}{number}.xml`

Is there an easy way to find the largest `{number}` for files that start with the prefix `"abc"`

Comment: Is the prefix always three characters? Is the number always a single digit?

Comment: No, do the iteration, substringing, number parsing and value checking...

Comment: yes, you can write custom sorting/filter predicate blocks or regular expressions or you can combine them to achieve your goal. the possibilities are limitless.

Comment: @woz no it is not always 3 chars, can be 4. But I can change that to make the prefix all the same length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *prefix = @"abc"; // adjust the prefix as needed
NSUInteger max = 0;

for (NSString *filename in myArray) {

    // if the prefix matches...
    if (filename.length >= prefix.length && [[filename substringToIndex:prefix.length] isEqualToString:prefix]) {

        // take away every character that's not a number
        NSString *numberAsString = [[filename componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]] 
                componentsJoinedByString:@""];

        // turn the NSString into an int
        NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
        int n = [[f numberFromString:numberAsString] integerValue];

        // update the maximum value if necessary
        if (n > max) max = n;

    }
}
```

Comment: NOTE: missing [ after && but as it was only 1 char stackoverflow wouldn't let me edit it